# EclipseLink all attributes are displayed as JSON

Tags: json, jpa, eclipselink, jpa-2.0

I have the following JPQL in Entity class

```
select new test.entity.Emp(o.empNo, o.empName) from Emp o
```

and in Service layer

```
@GET
@Path("/results")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<Emp> findAll() {
    Query query =             getEntityManager().createNamedQuery("Emp.findAll");
    List<Emp> result = query.getResultList();
    return result;
}
```

However when I run, all attributes are getting displayed in JSON result instead of `empNo` and `EmpName`.

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query returns new Emp objects (constructed only by empNo and empName), so this would be the result of your JSON string - whole Emp objects.

Create a class like this:

```
public class EmpDTO {
    private String empNo; //or whatever datatype you use...
    private String empName;

    public EmpDTO(String empNo, String empName) {
        this.empNo = empNo;
        this.empName = empName;
    }

    //getters and setters
}
```

Then edit your query to use this class in the constructor expression (change the package from test.dto to whatever you created your class in):

```
select new test.dto.EmpDTO(o.empNo, o.empName) from Emp o
```

Finally edit your code:

```
...
public List<EmpDTO> findAll() {
    Query query = getEntityManager().createNamedQuery("Emp.findAll");
    return query.getResultList();
}
```

BTW: `Emp.findAll` is not an ideal name for your namedQuery.

Comment: Your solution works well, but was wondering why I couldn't do this same in EMP class albeit I have constructor with String empNo, String empName as arguments.

Comment: The Emp class remains the same, there are always the same number of attributes in it, if you assign them or not.

Comment: You would need to change your JSON mappings so that null values are excluded from the JSON produced